# Counting complete cases by ID for several variables

Tags: r

I'm just beginning to learn R, so my apologies if this is simpler than I think it is, but I'm really struggling to find an answer.

What I'm attempting to do is to create a vector with a count of complete cases, by ID, for multiple variables.

For example, in this data frame:

```
ID<-c(1:5)
score.1<-c(1, 7, 3, 5, NA, 4, 6, 9, 11, NA)
score.2<-c(2, NA, 7, 6, NA, 5, NA, 7, 10, 1)
sample<-data.frame(ID, score.1, score.2)

ID score.1 score.2

  1       1       2
  2       7      NA
  3       3       7
  4       5       6
  5      NA      NA
  1       4       5
  2       6      NA
  3       9       7
  4      11      10
  5      NA       1
```

The output I'm looking for is something like:

```
ID Complete
1    4
2    2
3    4
4    4
5    1
```

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing? I've tried count(complete.cases(sample)) with plyr and sum(complete.cases()), but it's not giving me what I actually want.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: You can get a little creative with plyr's ddply function and get to the desired result.

sample$num_valid_score.1 <- ifelse(!is.na(score.1),1,0)
sample$num_valid_score.2 <- ifelse(!is.na(score.2),1,0)
sample$total_valid <- sample$num_valid_score.1 + sample$num_valid_score.2
ddply(sample,c("ID"),summarize,Complete=sum(total_valid))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>% 
  mutate(new_var = rowSums(!is.na(sample[,2:3]))) %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(Complete = sum(new_var))
```

The output is exactly what you are looking for:

```
 ID Complete
(int)    (dbl)
  1        4
  2        2
  3        4
  4        4
  5        1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
score.1_complete <- sample[complete.cases(sample$score.1), ]
score.2_complete <- sample[complete.cases(sample$score.2), ]

total <- rbind(score.1_complete, score.2_complete)

output <- count(total, "ID")
```

my reasoning:

`score.1_complete` selects the rows where score.1 (though not necessarily score.2) is complete.  `score.2_complete` selects the rows where score.2 (though not necessarily score.1) is complete.  therefore, counting how many times an ID shows up in `total` gives you how many times score.1 is complete for that ID + how many times score.2 is complete for that ID, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

with package dplyr and base function complete.cases, try

```
require(dplyr)
sample %>%
    mutate(complete = complete.cases(sample)) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(complete = sum(complete))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `gather/summarise`.  We convert the 'wide' to 'long' format with `gather` (from `tidyr`), get the `sum` of non-NA 'value' grouped by 'ID'.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(sample, score, value,-ID) %>%
           group_by(ID) %>%\
           summarise(value= sum(!is.na(value)) )
#     ID value
#   (int) (int)
#1     1     4
#2     2     2
#3     3     4
#4     4     4
#5     5     1
```

---

Or a `base R` approach would be

```
tapply(rowSums(!is.na(sample[-1])), sample$ID, FUN=sum)
#  1 2 3 4 5 
#  4 2 4 4 1
```